# What was the Free Trader society's debt to Baslim in Heinlein's Citizen of the Galaxy?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, slavery, citizen-of-the-galaxy

Did Colonel Richard Baslim rescue a Free Trader starship's crew from slavery or were the free traders trying their hand at slave trade and Baslim stopped them? If the former,  why were the traders so ashamed, answering Torby's inquiry with:

> "...a taboo was placed on it, the thing was so shameful that we never
>    talk about it."
>
> <sub>~Citizen of the Galaxy - Chapter 14</sub>

How is being hit by a slaver's 'paralyzing ray' and enslaved is so shameful a subject that it can't even be mentioned in the free trader community?

Comment: Unless the author wrote about it elsewhere it seems unlikely there is an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I first read this book when I was very young and starting to enjoy such of the Heinlein "juveniles" as I could find in local libraries. Several years later, maybe the third or fourth time I read the novel, I started asking myself much the same question as yours: "What's so shameful about being rescued from slavers? I can understand *gratitude* toward the rescuer, but where does *unspeakable shame* enter into it?"

I finally developed a hypothesis. There's a key passage from Chapter 14 which was probably the major influence on my thinking at the time. I'll quote it; then I'll explain what I suspect it means. Thorby is talking to Fritz (his adoptive brother) about Baslim's past.

> "Uh, I am curious about one thing. What was the debt that made
>   Grandmother willing to adopt me?"
>
> "Uh, 'I have said enough.'"
>
> "You know best."
>
> "Oh, confound it, the rest of the People know! It's bound to come up
>   at this Gathering."
>
> "Don't let me talk you into anything, Fritz."
>
> "Well . . . look, Baslim wasn't always a beggar."
>
> "So I long since figured out."
>
> "What he was is not for me to say. A lot of People kept his secret for
>   years; nobody has told me that it is all right to talk. But one fact
>   is no secret among the People . . . and you're one of the People. A long
>   time ago, Baslim saved a whole Family. The People have never forgotten
>   it. The *Hansea*, it was . . . the *New Hansea* is sitting right over there.
>   The one with the shield painted on her. I can't tell you more, because
>   a taboo was placed on it -- the thing was so shameful that we never
>   talk about it. I have said enough. But you could go over to the *New
>   Hansea* and ask to look through her old logs. If you identified
>   yourself -- who you are in relation to Baslim -- they couldn't refuse.
>   Though the Chief Officer might go to her cabin afterwards and have
>   weeping hysterics."
>
> "Hmm . . . I don't want to know badly enough to make a lady cry. Fritz?
>   Let's try this ride." So they did -- and after speeds in excess of
>   light and accelerations up to one hundred gravities, Thorby found a
>   roller coaster too exciting. He almost lost his lunch.

In this passage, as we become aware just a bit later as the plot develops, *one* of the things Fritz was holding back was that Baslim had been a career military officer, "Colonel Baslim of the Hegemonic Guard," until he took his crippling injuries and transferred over to intelligence work (a branch known as "the 'X' Corps"). In recent years Baslim had been working undercover as a one-legged beggar in Jubbulpore, and the People had scrupulously protected his secrets while carrying encrypted messages for him when they could. This was something they wouldn't have done for anyone else who had not been born within their culture. But admitting to those simple facts wouldn't cause the Chief Officer of the *New Hansea* to have a *nervous breakdown*, would it?

Fritz's talk about "taboo" and "so shameful that we never talk about it" and so forth, combined with his prediction of how the Chief Officer would react if Thorby absolutely insisted upon studying the ship's records, led me to the following conclusion:

Once upon a time, a Free Trader ship was captured by slavers. But not just by sheer bad luck, as occasionally happens. This time there was a Judas in their midst who was somehow bribed to betray the trust of his entire clan (the dozens of other people who lived in, and operated, the ship). Someone was willing to sell his relatives down the river as long as he personally made out like a bandit. When Colonel Baslim led the rescue party which liberated the captives of the *Hansea*, and which cost Baslim himself one leg and one eye before all the shooting was over, this really rubbed the People's noses in the fact that sometimes even a mere "fraki" could exhibit great honor and courage in risking his own neck in defense of some of the People (with whom he had no family ties, and to whom he had owed no previous debt), in sharp contrast to the way someone born and raised in their culture had exhibited a profound lack of honor when he sold his soul (and sold out his own kith and kin) in exchange for filthy lucre. (Or whatever he was offered -- perhaps his own private harem of beautiful slave girls, or something along those lines? We can't tell what the precise incentive was.)

For all I know, the unnamed person in question might have been severely mentally ill, and thus not fully responsible for his (or her) own acts. But that's sheer speculation.

This explains why the current Chief Officer might break down and cry if she were forced to dig out those records and let Thorby see them. Because of the reminder of the disgraceful behavior of one of her own relatives, a few decades ago -- something she presumably prefers to never even think about if she can avoid it.

Here's another quote, from a scene in Chapter 10, in which Captain Fjalar Krausa is explaining to Thorby about how he, as Baslim's adopted or foster "son" for many years (before he recently became Krausa's adopted son), could arguably be considered as having secretly been a member of the People all that time, even if he didn't know it!

> He changed the subject. "In a way, lad, you were always of the People."
>
> "Huh? Excuse me, Father?"
>
> "Son, Baslim the Cripple was an honorary member of the People."
>
> "What? How, Father? What ship?"
>
> "All ships. He was elected at a Gathering. Son, a long time ago a
>   shameful thing happened. Baslim corrected it. It put all the People in
>   debt to him. I have said enough. Tell me, have you thought of getting
>   married?"
>
> Marriage was the last thing on Thorby's mind; he was blazing anxious
>   to hear more about what Pop had done that had made him incredibly one
>   of the People. But he recognized the warning with which an elder
>   closed a taboo subject.

So my reconstruction would go this way: At a Gathering of all the clans, there was a big vote to make Baslim an honorary member because of his recent rescue of the *Hansea's* people. This was done partly out of gratitude, and perhaps partly because it retroactively made everybody feel better about the idea that "the horrible betrayal by one of our own was corrected *by another one of our own* -- as opposed to just having been corrected by some mere fraki!"

And if Baslim was one of the People, then any son of his could make a claim to being a long-lost relative of the People, even though I doubt anyone consciously had that point in mind at the time they first elected Baslim to honorary People status. (We never hear about his having been married with children during his military career, so I doubt there was any need to raise the issue, at that old Gathering, of whether or not his new status should be considered to carry over to his sons and daughters.)

Anyway, all of the above is the best I can do at making some deductions from the available clues.

Note: You asked about the possibility that the entire ship had been somehow involved in the slave trade (as willing participants, rather than as victims). I don't think so. For one thing, there's a bit where Colonel Brisby and his Executive Officer (Vice Colonel Stancke) are reminiscing about Baslim -- both of them had known him, in different times and places.

> "I'm no hero. I'm more the salt of the earth. Pappy, were you with him
>   in the rescue of the *Hansea*?"
>
> "You think I would fail to wear the ribbon? No, thank goodness; I had
>   been transferred. That was a hand-weapons job. Messy."

The "rescue" -- not the "capture." So I don't think anyone had accused the entire ship's crew, or even just its upper leadership (such as the Captain and the Chief Officer and their department heads) of conspiring to aid and abet in the enslavement of other people. Instead, they (or most of them) had somehow been captured alive and were facing a miserable existence from then on -- until Baslim came to the rescue.

If the whole extended family aboard the ship -- or at least several of its senior members -- had all "gone rogue" at once, I really don't think that ship, and its occupants, would ever have been welcomed back with open arms by the rest of the Free Traders. I think the evidence suggests there was just one very bad apple in the barrel who caused all the trouble. Presumably, he died (during or shortly after Baslim's raid, either killed in the heat of battle, or else executed after a quick trial by his peers if he'd been captured alive during the rescue mission), and the rest of the survivors of the *Hansea* were able to go back to "business as usual" since everybody knew that none of them had done anything vile. But the embarrassing memory still hung over them like a cloud.

Comment: Well reasoned based on scant evidence. Nice write-up.

Comment: Removed 'New' from two references to the Hansea, since they are plainly referencing the ship that was rescued.  The implication in Fritz's revelation is that whatever happened caused the family of the Hansea to need a new ship, which became the New Hansea.  I didn't reason it as deeply as you did.  My assumption was that Baslim rescued the Hansea, and that they were ashamed that the People were put in a position of owing gratitude by their ship needing rescue, plus they lost the ship. Pirates, slavers, whatever. Slavers does answer more questions and is more shameful than other scenarios.

Comment: Very interesting answer, and thanks for writing it. I think your speculation about the "Judas" is plausible, but it remains only speculation. Essentially this is a Noodle Incident.

Answer (score 4):

I concur with Paul Johnson's scenario, but I disagree on the reason for the original Hansea being abandoned and replaced by the New Hansea.

As referenced, this "...was a hand-weapons job. Messy."

Obviously, Colonel Baslim's raiding party had to board the ship to rescue the Family of the Hansea, which means that most likely they had to cut or blow their way in.  Follow that with hand to hand combat and hand weapons fire, it is doubtful the original Hansea would be in any kind of spaceworthy condition.

My conjecture is that the rescue took place planetside, probably at a pirate base, and the rescued members had to be lifted off quickly, leaving the Hansea behind.

Comment: This sounds like a comment on the answer by Lorendiac rather than a new answer to the question.

Comment: To set the record straight on one thing -- I (Lorendiac) was the one who offered that hypothesis about how a situation could have arisen which put the People deeply in debt to Baslim, but with some aspects of it being so shameful that they never talked about the ugly details. Paul Johnson is just the last guy to have done a little *editing* on my post.

Comment: No. I forget which ship it was, but at the Gathering, Thorby's new adoptive father (captain) was discussing buying a ship and the "cleansing" that it would need given the events (Captain going insane IIRC). Much more likely that the Hansea would have been abandoned/sold as being too expensive to clean or cursed.

Comment: @JohnP Your hypothesis of "too expensive to clean or cursed" is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

(I've edited this post, in light of a Ben's valid post below about providing evidence to support speculation as to the reason for the Traders' taboo covering details of the Honsea capture and rescue. As for DavidW's comment about assuming the Honsea captives were freed, maybe I misunderstood, but the book seems very clear that they were indeed freed--that was the whole point of Colonel Baslim's "hand weapons job," for which everyone involved got medals and Baslim earned honorary Free Trader citizenship.)

I wonder if the People's "shame" about the Honsea rescue arose from something that Heinlein would never have been allowed to discuss in a juvenile novel in the 50s, but did manage to partly sneak past his editors: sexual assault of the Honsea captives before Baslim charged in to rescue them. My evidence:

1. The very first page of CotG mentions "matched blond girls" selling for a high price. The implication's about as clear as it could be, in a 1950s juvenile novel. (Heinlein revisits this same "virgin sex slave" trope in Time Enough for Love, in a far more "adult" fashion.)
2. Early on, Baslim tries to resolve Thorby's nightmares via hypnosis:

"An hour and a half later Baslim still squatted beside the sleeping boy. Sweat poured down wrinkles in his face and he felt badly shaken. To get the boy back to the time he wanted to explore it had been necessary to force him back through experiences disgusting even to Baslim, old and hardened as he was."

Baslim's extreme shock seems, to me, to point to abuse well beyond "mere" physical violence. If sexual abuse or worse was standard slaver practice (as it certainly is in the real world), and if that happened to the People's Honsea clan before Baslim and crew rescued them, that goes a long way toward the Free Traders placing a taboo over the whole episode.

The emphasis on Traders' obsession with their pride and reputation (as depicted by an author writing in the 1950s, when sex crimes against either women or men meant life-ruining loss of status and reputation, albeit in different ways) also could support the theory that Heinlein is hinting at this "fate worse than death" befalling the Honsea clan.

All the emphasis on the Traders Not. Discussing. Details. Ever! I Have Said Enough. --regarding the Honsea incident, could support this interpretation.

Side note: I wish Netflix or someone would produce a series, about Colonel Baslim's pre-Jubbulpore career. You can keep your Jubal Harshaw and Lazarus Long and Farnham and all them guys. I just want to read more about Baslim.

Comment: This seems sufficiently speculative to be [borderline for this venue](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/269/35859) ... [opinion should be backed up with facts and references](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: You seem to be supporting the first option - that the traders were freed - but you really should start by asserting that instead of leaving it to implication.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: the question about the rescue of the "Hansea" was "What's so shameful about being rescued from slavers? I can understand gratitude toward the rescuer, but where does unspeakable shame enter into it?"

My speculation on that intriguing situation in "Citizen of the Galaxy" I like the hypothesis put forth here that the Free Trader "Hansea" was betrayed into capture by slavers, although there is little to no evidence for the theory in the writing (however the novel was originally apparently cut down to remove passages not suitable for a juvenile genre novel--and also apparently for 8 part serialization.Wish we had those pages.)

Heinlein, despite writing some long books was a remarkably efficient writer with spare strokes sufficient to create memorable characters. For example, part of his efficiency was using the same character over and over in different garb; Col. Baslim, Kettlebelly Baldwin (who shows up twice), Col. Dubois and Mr. Matson, and to some extent Lazarus Long. This is the Wise Old Man who teaches and disciplines his proteges (usually the juvenile hero or heroine.) We recognize these people in their different costumes and fill in the descriptions  not on the page. And maybe fill in unwritten episodes, too.

The Trader Society is rich, comfortable but highly restrictive, hierarchical, possibly dynastic and leaving it is unthinkable culturally (and maybe is difficult strategically. Even Captain Krausa has to wiggle hard to get Thorby out of the ship and find a spare hour for his mission to hand him over to the Hegemonic Guard to settle his last debt to Col. Baslim.)  So it's possible a disgruntled Family member goes rogue to escape his life as a Free Trader and drop onto one of the myriad new planets they've called on, well paid for his betrayal. Personally I think the Family would hunt such a rogue down and dispatch him with extreme prejudice.

But my theory is one that is hinted in the book itself. When Free Trader ships engaged pirate slavers, they were expected to fight and if  the fight seemed lost, to self-destruct rather than to allow the crew (family) to be taken prisoner and enslaved. (This is in the chapters where Thorby is a junior weapons officer in Sisu) If the weapons officer,  or even the captain failed to issue the destruct order out of cowardice or hesitation and the ship became captive, that would be shameful. Ships disappear, vaulting off into space and then never heard from again (such as the newly twinned ship that indebted the Sisu and a few others.) A less experienced crew might engage a slaver and then have to self-destruct to avoid capture. So perhaps a ship failed to self-destruct (shame, cowardice) and ended up in the slave pens of a world

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Reading this I'm not clear what your answer is as to the debt owed to Baslim.  You should lead with a simple statement of the answer and then develop your argument.

Comment: In an earlier post" What's so shameful about being rescued from slavers? I can understand gratitude toward the rescuer, but where does unspeakable shame enter into it?"